# python3: python refuses to recognise tk install/ GUI modules don't work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning python via [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-python-by-making-games)

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.7

I have to use pyautogui like this

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
pyautogui.write( ' This is written by a computer')
```

On the video, the tutor switches to the text editor and just starts writing. Nothing happens on mine when I run this code.

So I go to the pyautogui docs and try the alertbox code sample just to see if I can get anything working.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.alert(text='', title='', button='OK')
```

This gives me the error `AssertionError: Tkinter is required for pymsgbox`

Similarly, on the video, using matplotlib allows drawing a graph with this code

```
import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

It tells me `Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure`. Then when I configure a GUI backend with `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` I fall into a loop where python3 reports `module not found: _tkinter` and simultaneously Ubuntu reports that `python3-tk` is the latest version so there's nothing to do.

So I've tried

- reinstalling python3
- installing python3-tk *then* reinstalling python
- pip install tk
- setting up venv and doing the above
- Google - but I only get the above answers. Which don't work.

So basically everything wants Tkinter but tk is there and python seems to just ignore it. I don't get it

Comment: `pip install tk` doesn't do anything useful. Try running: `sudo apt install python3.10-tk`.

Comment: `pip install tk` installs tensorkit, not tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone that replied. It turns out that the solution was to recompile Python from source, telling it at `configure` where to look for tkinter [as described in these instructions](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html)